# Creating a column from a condition with multiple macthes per row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Hi I have a list and a dataframe. I want to create a new column based on the matches from the list.

I'm able to run str.extract to find matches, but it only lists the first match then moves to the next row. How can I get all of the matches in each row to appear?

```
my list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

existing_col
   a b
   a c

df2['new_col'] = df2['existing_col'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(my_list)})', expand=False) 

existing_col    new_col
   a b            a 
   a b            c
```

This is essentially the result I am returned right now.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for all matches to lists:

```
print (df2)
  existing_col
0      a b d c
1      a c e q

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df2['new_col'] = df2['existing_col'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(my_list)})') 
print (df2)
  existing_col    new_col
0      a b d c  [a, b, c]
1      a c e q     [a, c]
```

If need output like joined strings e.g. by `,` separator add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df2['new_col'] = df2['existing_col'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(my_list)})').str.join(',') 
print (df2)
  existing_col new_col
0      a b d c   a,b,c
1      a c e q     a,c
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this and the last question I asked to ;)